# reading RSS returns different response on localhost

Tags: linq, rss

im trying to parse an rss feed on localhost, and it brings back the right results, but when i try to do that from another (preproduction server) and live, it returns a list of comments made by users on the hydrapinion website which is completely unrelated, have i been spoofed? how can i debug this? its just an rss feed and a simple LINQ code!

```
string bingurl = "http://www.bing.com/search?form=QBRE&filt=rf&qs=n&format=rss&count=10&q=+environment+(site:www.australianit.news.com.au)";

XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(bingurl);
IEnumerable<XElement> items = (from i in doc.Descendants("item")
                                       orderby DateTime.Parse(i.Element("pubDate").Value) descending
                                       select i).Take(10);
rpData.DataSource = items;
rpData.DataBind();
```

i tried a different combination, and i get no results at all! do u think the server settings have antyhing to do with retrieving rss results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found some decent guide for bing search, but as it turned out, bing doesnt bring decent resuls! and it appears to me it changes the results set according to where ur calling it from, i tried adding "loc:" to the rss, when called from code it returned different results than when called on bing website itself, i dont know the algorithm they are using but it is getting more obvious

the guide is here:
http://help.live.com/help.aspx?mkt=en-AU&project=a